# How to deal with missing operand error when trying to rm

Tags: bash, find, rm

I have the following code

```
rm "$torrent"/*.{txt,nfo,jpg} && echo "removed \"txt,nfo,jpg\" files"
```

If there are no files to delete then I get the "missing operand" error which I would like to avoid because it triggers an exit 1 for the script.

If I have the following code

```
rm -f "$torrent"/*.{txt,nfo,jpg} && echo "removed \"txt,nfo,jpg\" files"
```

the `rm` always evaluates to true even if there were no files deleted.

I want to display the message "removed .. files" if some files were deleted.  If no files were deleted I want silence with no errors thrown.

I toyed with

```
find "$torrent" -type f -name "*.txt" -or -name "*.nfo" -or -name ".jpg" -delete && echo "files were deleted"
```

but it always evaluated to true even if no files were deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rewrite it into a proper `if` statement:

```
if rm "$torrent"/*.{txt,nfo,jpg}
then
  echo "removed \"txt,nfo,jpg\" files"
if
```

This allows you to react to the exit status while `set -e` is in effect, without the script exiting

Comment: I have a `trap function() ERR` that logs the error and gives exit 1.  How do I "react" specifically to the error given from "missing operand" error?

Comment: The trap won't trigger in this example. 1. GNU rm doesn't differentiate, so you'd be better off checking that the glob expands to something first

Comment: I'm so confused right now.  I tried your example and it didn't trigger the trap.  I tried the first example in my post and it didn't trigger the trap.  But I swear that it triggered before.  I have ithe trap programmed to send an email on error and I was getting the emails.  Perhaps there is a difference in my example code and the code I'm using IRL.  The struggle continues.

Comment: It should be triggering on the first one, but `set -e` is an ugly beast so there are several caveats

Comment: I'm not using `set -e`.  This line of code in my IRL script is triggering the trap... `(shopt -s nocaseglob; rm "$torrent"/*sample*.{avi,mkv,mp4} && echo "removing sample video file")` when I'm not using `rm -f` and there are no sample videos.

Comment: This line of code doesn't trigger the trap...`rm "$torrent"/*.{txt,nfo,jpg} && echo "removing \"txt,nfo,jpg\" files"` in any case.

Comment: You're indirectly using it, since an ERR trap "means to execute ARG each time a command's failure would cause the shell to exit when the -e option is enabled." (man bash). It has all the same problems, like how a line in a function will or won't trap depending on the context the function is called

Comment: Wow.  Thanks!  That is so wonky.  Bash is the worst language I have ever used for so many reasons.  I guess I'm going to drop the the trap (and therefore the implicit `set -e`).  Thanks again!